# Why does subset(X,[1,2]) not generate all subsets?

Tags: prolog

I'm learning Prolog and it was my understanding that you can often ask the "reverse question", e.g. instead of using `member(X,Y)` to ask whether `X` is in `Y` , use it to generate all lists that contain `X`.

`subset(1,[1,2])` works, but `subset(X,[1,2])` returns `X = []` for some reason.

What is the reasoning?

(SWI-Prolog)

Comment: your question is subset.. your code is sublist..

Comment: Sorry, should have been subset.

Comment: Some predicates are designed to cut after they succeed once. For example, `memberchk/2` is such a predicate (it's the "succeed once" version of `member/2`).   SWI's implementation of `subset/2` succeeds if the first argument is a subset of the second and then quits. See the [manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subset%2f2) for `subset/2`. It says it uses `memberchk/2` to accomplish this.

Comment: The definition of `subset/2` in SWI is not a relation. The hints in the manual are often quite indirect . That is, "uses `memberchk/2`" can be read to this end.   `memberchk/2` is itself not a relation. Also it's documentation has to be read with some background knowledge...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments.